# Sharepoint Object Model applicaton cannot run outside of WSS server

Tags: sharepoint

I create a C# console application using Microsoft.SharePoint object model VS WSS extensions on Windows Server 2003.  The application is supposed to iterate WSS3.0 sites looking for all available lists.  It runs just fine on the server.  But if I try to run the exe from another computer on the network, the application crashes instantly on SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite("http://devsharepoint);
Even my try and catch doesn't help as catch is not executed.

Is it intended to run the Sharepoint object model applications only on machines with VS SharePoint extensions installed?

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace ConsoleApplicationWSSobjectModel
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "http://sharepoint";
            Console.WriteLine("Trying to access: " + url);
            try
            {

                SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(url);//"http://Server_Name");
                SPWebCollection sites = siteCollection.AllWebs;

                foreach (SPWeb site in sites)
                {
                    SPListCollection lists = site.Lists;

                    Console.WriteLine("Site: " + site.Name + "  Lists: " + lists.Count.ToString());
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to continue");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use `Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)`. Use `Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())`

Comment: You are right John, my bad.
Val

Comment: Erm - use .Message if you just want the message, .ToString() if you want everything including the stack trace. Most of the time you do, but not always.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot use the SP object model ”outside sharepoint” you will have to use web services (or if your go with sharepoint 2010 you can use the new client object model)

Answer (score 3):

Anything built with the SharePoint object model can only run on a server with SharePoint installed. There is however no dependency on the VS extensions.

Comment: Oh, dear...  Well, back to web services then ;-)

Thank you all.

Comment: @Val: Mark it as answered, it will help someone in need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Client Object Model using C# or VB as your language. Add references Microsoft.sharepoint.client.dll and Microsoft.sharepoint.client.Runtime.dll it can be found under 14(SP2010) or 15(SP2013) hive ISAPI folder.